how to translate textEditController without disturbing calculation logic in a calculator
I have a calculator that can change language and i want to translate user input data over screen and perform calculation without showing number insted translated number.
Here are my provider methods that i have tried so far.
  void calculate() {
    final expression = inPutController.text.trim();
    if (expression.isEmpty) {
      outPutController.text = '';
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }

    try {
      double result = evaluateExpression(expression);
      outPutController.text = langOutPut(context!, result.toString());
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      outPutController.text = '';
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  String langOutPut(BuildContext context, String expression) {
    final localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

    return expression.split('').map((char) {
      switch (char) {
        case '.':
          return localizations.period;
        case '0':
          return localizations.zero;
        case '00':
          return localizations.doubleZero;
        case '1':
          return localizations.one;
        case '2':
          return localizations.two;
        case '3':
          return localizations.three;
        case '4':
          return localizations.four;
        case '5':
          return localizations.five;
        case '6':
          return localizations.six;
        case '7':
          return localizations.seven;
        case '8':
          return localizations.eight;
        case '9':
          return localizations.nine;
        default:
          return char;
      }
    }).join('');
  }

lnCalculator
Translate the user input and output
